# data display at the same raw in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, html, laravel-5.1

I'm having a problem with fetching the data from database to HTML table..

After the data is displayed in the table, all the data from same column is displaying in the same raw 
I tried to use loop to dived them into multiple rows but it didn't work ..

Here are my codes 
table name meeting

```
Controls.php
public function meetingdet()
{
       $meeting = DB::table('meeting')->get();
       return view('My_Work.Editor_first', ['meetings' => $meeting]);
}
```

view.php

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
   <td>
<?php

   foreach ($meetings as $meeting) {
       echo $meeting->date;  
   }
   ?>
</td>
<td>
<?php
   foreach ($meetings as $meeting) {
       echo $meeting->meetingname;  
   }
   ?>
</td>
</tr>
    @endfor
```

Another issue 
I'm trying the same way for fetching the data like this in another page but the problem is, it is showing for me the same things from this page in the other pages even the html page is different.

Another Issue 
I am using date picker and trying to store the date in mysql as date but it store for me as 0000-00-00

```
 {!! Form::text('date', ' ', array('id' => 'datepicker')) !!}
```

this is my insert command

```
$mstore = \DB::table('meeting')->insert(['date' => $request->input('date')]);
```

and I'm working on laravel 5.1 
I really need help in this

Thank you

Best Regards

Comment: Can you do: `dd($request->input('date'));` before the `DB::table('meeting')...` line, and then write on here what is displayed?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Change 
`$mstore = \DB::table('meeting')->insert(['date' => $request->input('date')]);` 
to
`dd($request->input('date')); $mstore = \DB::table('meeting')->insert(['date' => $request->input('date')]);`
Then save some data, and it should display some text on the page. Copy and paste what is shown, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your problem, but the initial question is a bit confusing. Try this in your view

```
@foreach($meetings as $meeting)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $meeting->date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $meeting->meetingname }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

As for the date picker, you will need to view the date you are sending to the server. Make sure you are actually sending a date in the correct format to the server, before you save it.

Comment: It worked..!! the next problem the date picker I have edit my question please check it out

Comment: I knew what is my second problem but still I cant fix the date